# javascript object reference by shortcuts

Tags: javascript

I have very very valuable , so i tried to make shortcuts like this :

LIVE example : http://jsfiddle.net/nqeUN/

```
var d = "document" ,
    t = "getElementByTagName" ,
    d = "div" ,
    oc = "onclick";
d[t](d)[0].oc = function(){
    alert("1");
}
```

but it's not working , what is the reason? i can see in Google plus api that all the objects are defined like this , as strings , how do they make it work?

Comment: IMO the "convenience" of a few less keystrokes is not worth the impact on code readability. If you are worried about delivering smaller `.js` files, read SLaks' answer.

Comment: DO NOT CODE THIS WAY.  It makes your code utterly unreadable and will be responsible for many bugs and much longer development.  Further, if anyone else every needs to work on your code, they will be totally unproductive.  If you want smaller code, write normal javascript and use a minifier on the final result before deployment.  Even if `d[t](d)[0].oc = ` was correct code, it is highly cryptic and unreadable.

Comment: @jfriend00: I completely agree that this code will be unclear to others. But at the same time `document.getElementsByTagName` can't be minified. I think the technique is alright since it does allow the code to be minified, but certainly better variable names are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings will work for properties, but not variable names. You also define `d` twice, and have the wrong method name. You would be able to do this:

```
var d = 'document', t = 'getElementsByTagName', div = 'div', oc = 'onclick';

window[d][t](div)[0][oc] = function() { ... }
```

But this really reduces readability and isn't necessary. You could run your code through a minimizer to get this automatically and still maintain readable dev code.

Comment: that's what i was looking for , i don't want to be greedy but i can get either "window" as a string somehow?

Comment: @MorSela `var gg = "gg", w = "window"; w[gg]()[d][t](div)[0][oc] = function() { ... }` all strings, checkmate! requires `String.prototype.gg = function(){return window[this.toString()];}`

Comment: Getting `window` as a string isn't very practical, but you could do `var w = window;` and then use `w` from then on.

Comment: @MorSela: You don't need to get `window` at all since `document` is globally available. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795930/javascript-object-reference-by-shortcuts/7796027#7796027). You just need to use `var d=document` instead of `var d="document"`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems you need to address

- You have two values bound to `d`: `"document"` and `"div"`.
- It's getElement**s**ByTagName
- The `getElementsByTagName` function needs a DOM entry point not a string.  Switch the first `d` to `document`
- When using dot notation for `.oc` it will bound to the property `oc` in stead of the value of the variable `oc`.  Use `[]` notation instead

Code:

```
var d = document ,
    t = "getElementsByTagName" ,
    div = "div" ,
    oc = "onclick";

d[t](div)[0][oc] = function(){
    alert("1");
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqeUN/1/

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a string, not `document`.

You should write `var d = document` to get the actual `document` object.

---

However, you should not do this yourself; it makes *utterly* unreadable code.

Instead, you should develop normal, readable Javascript, then use a minifier (such as [Microsoft AjaxMin](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) or [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/)) to automatically shrink your code as much as possible in production.

Comment: on the google plus api they set the document as a string , how do they make it work?

Answer (score 1):

if you replace the values in your example, you'll see:

```
"document".getElementsByTagName("document").onclick = function() {};
```

1.) `d` should be set to the global document reference, not the string 'document'

```
var d = window.document;
```

2.) `getElementsByTagName` returns nodes that match the given tag name that are contained within the given DOM node, so passing 'document' as a string would look for HTML elements named 'document'. you need to find the divs, for example:

```
d.getElementsByTagName("div"); // All the 'div' elements in the document
```

3.) For method names to be used as strings, they need to be in brackets

```
document[ t ]; // document.t won't work, t is not a member
```

4.) Once you've accessed the nodes you care about, you need to loop through them to add event handlers to each element

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    i = 0,
    len = d.length;

for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
    (function() {
        // do something with d[i], the current element in the loop
    })(i)
}
```

hope that helps! cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable `d` is a string; and the `String` object does not have a `getElementByTagName` method.

Furthermore, your `d` variable is being redeclared as the string `div`; so you need to assign  that to a different name:

```
var d = "document" ,
    t = "getElementByTagName" ,
    e = "div" ,
    oc = "onclick";
```

Then, you need to access the `window` object, and retrieve the `document` attribute of it:

```
window[d]
```

to retrieve the `Document` element, and then retrieve the `getElementsByTagName` method from it (read **getElements** not **getElement**)

```
window[d][t]
```

You then invoke it and pass it the name of the element, retrieve the first value of the returned array, and assign a function to its `onclick` attribute:

```
window[d][t](e)[0][oc] = function () {
    alert("1");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = "document",
    t = "getElementsByTagName" ,
    div = "div" ,
    oc = "onclick";
window[d][t](div)[0][oc] = function(){
    alert("1");
}
```

1. ) document is not a string
2. ) document['getElementByTagName'].call(this, 'div')
3. ) `.` accessor changed to bracket because oc is a string not a property
4. ) you used to `var d` twice
5. ) it's `getElementsByTagName`, plural Elements

Comment: on the google plus api they set the document as a string , how do they make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Full string madness http://jsfiddle.net/nqeUN/8/

```
"document"["gg"]()["getElementsByTagName"]("div")["0"]["onclick"] = function(){alert(1);};
```